# log one ip only at once

Tags: php, logging

hello i have code that log ips and saves it at visitors.log

i am log ips [here](http://colorswitch2.com/test/)

```
$line = "$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]";
file_put_contents('visitors.log', $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

but i want to log 1 ip only at once....

that code logs every user on every refresh...

or how can i shown that code to users to every 48 hour?
i need solution
thanks..
after that i want to use that ips to block some content for that...
so i want to save one ip only at once..

Comment: You can save IP on session. Then check session. This is expandable if works for you. By the way, you better save in database if you want to use them latter.

Comment: you know that the ip of the common user changes every now and then? And yes, it's much better to save that in a database. Also it's much easier to check if the ip was added in the last 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if it this what you want, so you want only 1 ip logged?

create a table on your database like

table ip[id, ip_address] or use a file is the same.

and when a user log in check is IP and register on db/file, when he goes out remove it, or create a col in user table called ip_address and atribute 1 ip per user

this is the easy way of course, there some problems but do the thing

one of the problems i think this have is : if the user just close the browser, he dont clicked on logout button so you dont know if he logouts..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
echo (strpos(file_get_contents('ips.txt'), $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) !== false)?'dablokilia':$line = "$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]";
file_put_contents('ips.txt', $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);;

?>
```

that code working...